# indexing a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of pandas data frames like so:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, d5]
```

where each df has different shape. I would like to write a function that iterates through this list and for each data frame in df_list, locate the index of the data frame in that list and *do something with the index*, not the data frame itself.

For lists like `l = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']` the method `l.index('string2')` returns the integer position of string. However, doing

```
df_list.index(df1)
```

returns the `ValueError: can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects.`

What is the reason for this error or the inconsistency when the objects in the list are not identically labeled? Is there a better indexing method in this case?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The problem stems from how dataframes implement `==`.

Comment: There is no "error or the inconsistency". The list contains objects, yet you are asking for the index of the string `'df1'`. That string doesn't exist in `df_list` so it returns a `ValueError`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not ask for the index of the string 'df1', rather df1. That was a typo.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that makes sense. I would like to iterate through the list, call df.plot, but fig.add_subplot() requires an index in the third tuple position. I can use some other kind of integer index though. I was just curious why it worked for some lists and not for others.

Comment: well, if you just want to iterate through the list with the corresponding indices and elements, just do `for i, df in enumerate(df_list): ...`

Comment: Understood. Thank you